# My Tracking Pixels Get Blocked By EFA-Projects.org

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, tracking, massmail

On December 2014, my email blaster application (built by CI Framework) running smoothly on a hosting. 
Here is the complete img tag (opened using Gmail):

```
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/b1Ud84K8P6C6Yso9MhNwumluc4XG16f2bC1IK0SaJRjkHrNoY6zmdAAwXvC1TTdN1OEj_-GXvE94xgNfGNxy_JTQiZ-LQfa47AwaiTUw4dHYR-F-04rhakp3Ha7BqjmitIaGUQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.domain.tld/email/received/ac26b0194082cb1ceb93c480a48388f1" width="1" height="1" class="CToWUd">
```

But, later, exactly after 1st January 2015, my tracking image get blocked by EFA-Projects.org. So i could not tracking open email via my tracking pixel anymore.
Here is the complete img tag:

```
<img src="http://dl.efa-project.org/static/1x1spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="Web Bug from http://www.domain.tld/email/received/78d705691857b9f9f4c20ebe20e40d7d">
```

and Here is the received function:

```
public function received($code = NULL){
    if(!empty($code)){
        $blasted_email = $this->BlastedEmail->first(array('been_read_code' => $code));
        if ($blasted_email) {
            $blasted_email->been_read = "Yes";
            $blasted_email->save();
        }
    }
    header_remove();
    //header("Content-Length: 0");
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
    header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

    $img = file_get_contents('http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img537/2260/shWlm6.gif');
    echo $img;
}
```

imageshack in here is used to return an image.

I have done troubleshooting more than 6 hours to find why my src attribute changed to `http://dl.efa-project.org/static/1x1spacer.gif`
but I could not find anything till I asked this question.

Any answer will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.outpostfirewall.com/guide/faq/web_bugs.htm
http://www.mailscanner.info/man/MailScanner.conf.5.html

You've been pwned by efa.  Web bug disarmed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should include the relevant information from those links in your answer.